# "Unable to login with provided credentials" (on Testing)

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I'm programming a test case for user register and login, I tested whit postman (chrome) and it works but the test case doesn't.
I'm using `djangorestframework-jwt` for authentication

Test:

```
class PublicUserTests(APITestCase):

    def test_create_account(self):
        url = "/api/user/create/"
        data = {'email': 'clark@gmail.com', 'nombre': 'Clark', 'password': 'Clark'}
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.data)

    def test_login(self):
        url = "/api/auth/token/"
        response = self.client.post(url, {"email": "clark@gmail.com", "password": "Clark"}, format='json')
        print(response.status_text)
        print(response.content)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK, response.data)
```

Result:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.BAD REQUEST
b'{"non_field_errors":["Unable to login with provided credentials."]}'
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_login (user.tests.PublicUserTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rizotas/Proyects/django/src/rescue/user/tests.py", line 86, in test_login
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK, response.data)
AssertionError: 400 != 200 : ReturnDict([('non_field_errors', ['Unable to login with provided credentials.'])])

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.116s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Thanks so much for help me :)

Comment: Have you tried using self.client.login()?

Comment: yes, but it return False, thanks.

Comment: I found a way for that works, joined the two functions, but this is a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test methods in TestCase is not connected. So when `test_login` works he does not see user from `test_create_account`.

You need to create user before login in `test_login`.